# converting array of objects to simple array

Tags: php

I have an array of objects, each object consists of an id and an organisation.  It looks like this

```
Array ( 
  [0] => stdClass Object ( 
      [id] => 2 [organisation] => org1
  )   
  [1] => stdClass Object ( 
      [id] => 4 [organisation] => org2
   ) 
  [2] => stdClass Object ( 
      [id] => 1 [organisation] => org3
  ) 
)
```

I need to convert it into a simple associative array ([id]=>organisation,...) so the above example would look like this

```
Array (
    [2] => org1
    [4] => org2
    [1] => org3
)
```

Greatful for any thoughts

Comment: So what is wrong with leaving the objects as they are and using `$arry[$x]->organisation` or `foreach ($array as $obj ) { echo $obj->organisation; }` Its much easier to read later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through it using a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) statement and append it to another array.

```
$finished = [];

foreach($array as $arr) {
    $finished[$arr->id] = $arr->organisation;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = array();
foreach($array as $arr) {
    $result[$arr->id] = $arr->organisation;
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($result);
```