# convert std object array to simple php array

Tags: php, arrays

my code so far

```
<?php
foreach($sub_category as $row2){

    $url = 'https://myurl.com';  
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 3);     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
   
    echo $name." data = "."<pre>"; print_r($data);
}


?>
```

This is $data output

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [course_title] => 60+ Space Facts To Get An A In Astronomy
            [description] =>  60+ Space Facts To Get An "A" In Astronomy
            [image] => pexels-pixabay-39896_20210220014840929292735.jpg
            
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            
            [course_title] => Learn Chinese
            [description] => Learn Chinese
            [image] => Chinoabc_20211227114307692406780.png
            
        )
 )
```

I want to convert it to look like below

```
Array
        (
            [0] => array
                (
                    [course_title] => 60+ Space Facts To Get An A In Astronomy
                    [description] =>  60+ Space Facts To Get An "A" In Astronomy
                    [image] => pexels-pixabay-39896_20210220014840929292735.jpg
                    
                )
        
            [1] => array
                (
                    
                    [course_title] => Learn Chinese
                    [description] => Learn Chinese
                    [image] => Chinoabc_20211227114307692406780.png
                    
                )
         )
```

i have tried many answers from here
[converting array of objects to simple array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384389/converting-array-of-objects-to-simple-array)
but it's not working for me

i have tried many answers from already posted questions. my problem is different than any other relevant question posted here

Comment: When you enable `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` then `curl_exec()` returns a string. Unless I'm missing something, `$data` is not an array of objects, it's just a text that happens to contain a PHP variable dump for some reason. It may be more obvious if you replace `print_r()` with `var_dump()`.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't write `$data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));`?

Comment: APIs don't usually return `print_r()` output, they usually return JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `(array)` type cast to convert an object to an equivalent associative array.

```
$data = array_map(function($x) { return (array)$x; }, $data);
```

If the original array of objects came from using `json_decode()`, you can tell it to return associative arrays instead of objects by giving it a `true` second argument.

```
$data = json_decode($data, true);
```

Comment: tried but not working for me the array #1 is stored inside $data var, i use array_map function $x = $data right ?, i am getting 2 errors 1= Message: Undefined variable: array & 2= Message: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array

Comment: please review this change https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70656613/revisions

Comment: `$array` is your array.

Comment: I've updated the answer to use your variable.

Comment: good finding you were correct the data was not json object that's why not working as array but simple string now in source i use $data =json_encode($data,true); than used your $data = json_decode($data, true);
and yes done now i have string as an array ready to use thumbs up :)